# How to use session variables in DAO layer?

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I have a @SessionScoped ApplicationBean for storing user login info and injecting it into other managed beans successfully as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356990/how-to-access-variable-in-sessionscoped-managed-bean).

I also use my Dao interfaces by @ManagedProperty annotation but I feel something wrong with my usage.

Assume that there is as StockDao that has a public method listStocks(String companyCode) and companyCode is stored in the ApplicationBean when user logins.

So my managed bean is calling the DAO layer like this

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{appBean}")
ApplicationBean appBean;

public void getStockList() {    
    return stockDao.listStocks(appBean.getCompanyCode());       
}
```

This repeats everywhere where the sql needs companyCode.

I feel that it would be better if my DAO layer had known companyCode (which means injecting ApplicationBean into DAOs) and I should use my methods like below

```
public void getStockList() {    
    return stockDao.listStocks();       
}
```

So the question is, which API design would be better and if you vote for the second, how can I inject @SessionScoped beans into DAO layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me 1st approach is much cleaner , 
i  dont want to tie DAO layer with the session managed bean.

I keep my general artifacts especially daos and data models packaged as a seperate Jar , without any external dependencies
This way i could use the same without any modifications be it a Web App , Stand Alone or in an EJB

This keeps your Dao independent of how/where the Company Code is fetched  from

Answer (score 2):

You do not use session variables in the DAO layer. Lack of business logic and user interface matters is exactly what makes it DAO: a layer responsible just for abstracting data access.

If you add session-dependent state, you will turn your DAO layer into DAAMUIS layer (the ubiquitous *Data Access And Miscellaneous User Interface Stuff* layer). I am not saying that DAAMUIS is wrong or evil, just that the question needs rephrasing.