# Passing a field from one managed bean to another

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing

Is there some way that I can pass a Object from one managed bean to another

For Example: `#{bean1.setMethod(bean2.getMethod)}`

*OR*

Are there any workarounds of doing this?

Comment: There are MANY ways to do that. The right way depends on the functional requirement and/or technical problem which is *nowhere* visible in the question in its current form. You'll have more chance in getting the right way answered if you tell about the functional requirement and/or technical problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Or search for al the very similar question and pick the answer from the one that matches your case

Comment: Are your looking for [bean injection](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356990/how-to-access-property-of-sessionscoped-managed-bean-in-viewscoped-managed-bean/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ForguesR for answering the question. The solution to the problem is [here](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther).